# Fetch data form pivot tables with one query using laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, pivot-table

What is the best way to get the 3rd table data with one query.

```
User   :   id | name    
Event  :   id | user_id  
Likes  :   id | user_id | event_id

Here is my  Eloquent Query

$events = Event::with('likes','users')->get();

return view('events',compact('events'));

In views i am iterating over all events like this,
User has multiple events as well as multiple likes in relation model.


@foreach($events as $event)

 {{ $event->name }}
 {{ $like_id }} //show like id if it is liked by the user

     // I have to execute another loop only to check if it is liked or not 
      @foreach($row->likes as $like)

             @if(Auth::id() == $like->user_id)
                   Liked
             @endif
      @endforeach

@endforeach
```

> Now i need to check if the logged in user has liked this event or not ?
>   along with all the events whether they are liked or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try as:

```
@foreach($events as $event)

    {{ $event->name }}
    {{ $event->likes->count() }}

    @if($event->likes->contains('user_id', Auth::id()))
         Liked
    @endif

@endforeach
```